# Inherit MGLPolygon in Mapbox iOS SDK 3.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to define a class Building which inherits MGLPolygon.
MGLPolygon is defined as:

```swift
public class MGLPolygon : MGLMultiPoint, MGLOverlay {

    public var interiorPolygons: [MGLPolygon]? { get }

    public convenience init(coordinates coords: UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: UInt)

    public convenience init(coordinates coords: UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: UInt, interiorPolygons: [MGLPolygon]?)
}
```

MGLPolygon's designated initializer is hidden in the swift version of SDK. The following would fail:

```swift
class Building: MGLPolygon {

    let name: String

    init(name: String, coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]){
        self.name = name
        super.init(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
        // Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'MGLPolygon'
    }
}
```

I checked the [original SDK code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/darwin/src/MGLPolygon.mm) in Objective-C:

```swift
@implementation MGLPolygon

@dynamic overlayBounds;

+ (instancetype)polygonWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords count:(NSUInteger)count {
    return [self polygonWithCoordinates:coords count:count interiorPolygons:nil];
}

+ (instancetype)polygonWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords count:(NSUInteger)count interiorPolygons:(NSArray<MGLPolygon *> *)interiorPolygons {
    return [[self alloc] initWithCoordinates:coords count:count interiorPolygons:interiorPolygons];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coords count:(NSUInteger)count interiorPolygons:(NSArray<MGLPolygon *> *)interiorPolygons {
    if (self = [super initWithCoordinates:coords count:count]) {
        if (interiorPolygons.count) {
            _interiorPolygons = interiorPolygons;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (mbgl::LinearRing<double>)ring {
    NSUInteger count = self.pointCount;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates = self.coordinates;

    mbgl::LinearRing<double> result;
    result.reserve(self.pointCount);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push_back(mbgl::Point<double>(coordinates[i].longitude, coordinates[i].latitude));
    }
    return result;
}

- (mbgl::Annotation)annotationObjectWithDelegate:(id <MGLMultiPointDelegate>)delegate {
    mbgl::Polygon<double> geometry;
    geometry.push_back(self.ring);
    for (MGLPolygon *polygon in self.interiorPolygons) {
        geometry.push_back(polygon.ring);
    }

    mbgl::FillAnnotation annotation { geometry };
    annotation.opacity = [delegate alphaForShapeAnnotation:self];
    annotation.outlineColor = [delegate strokeColorForShapeAnnotation:self];
    annotation.color = [delegate fillColorForPolygonAnnotation:self];

    return annotation;
}

@end
```

However, unfortunately I'm not good with Objective-C and I don't understand the code.

### What am I asking?

What is the designated initializer of MGLPolygon in Swift? What does it take as parameters?

### Extra question

Why is the designated initializer hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to create a class method in your subclass (e.g. `+buildingWithCoordinates:count:`) which calls `super`'s implementation in order to handle this.

Comment: I know that. I need to understand how that is exactly done(I don't fully understand Obj-C code). What I figured out from the code above is that even obj-c code doesn't fully expose the implementation. Am I right?

Comment: I am seeing identical problems with Apple's `MKPolygon` as well when bridged to Swift.

Comment: And this seems to be a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286961/objective-c-sub-classing-basics-how-to-add-custom-property

Comment: Based on this, I think you are better off creating a protocol for your needs, subclassing `MGLPolygon` without including any initializers, and then making your class conform to your protocol.

Answer (score 0):

My solution according to @incanus's advice:

```
class Building: MGLPolygon {

    var name: String?

    afterInit(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

func initBuilding(name: String, coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> Building {
    let building = Building(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
    building.afterInit(name)
    return building
}
```

It's not elegant but it works.